# How can write query to show list in hibernate criteria

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, hibernate-criteria, map-projections

**Employee.java**

```
@Table(name="EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee {

@Id
@Column(name = "wid")
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer wid;

@Column(name = "wname")
private String wname;

@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "bidd")
private BloodGroup bloodgroup;

@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "sidd")
private Section section;
     .....
  //Getters And Setters
 }
```

**BloodGroup.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="BLOODGROUP")
public class BloodGroup {

@Id
@Column(name = "bid")
@GeneratedValue (strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer bid;

@Size(min=1,max = 30)
@Column(name = "blood_name")
private String blood_name;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "bloodgroup",fetch=FetchType.LAZY, 
targetEntity=Employee.class, cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
private List<Employee> emp;
     .....
  //Getters And Setters
 }
```

**Section.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SECTION")
public class Section {

@Id
@Column(name = "sid")
@GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer sid;

@Column(name = "sname")
@Size(min = 2 , max = 30)
private String sname;


@OneToMany(mappedBy = "section",fetch=FetchType.LAZY, 
 targetEntity=Employee.class, cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)

private List<Employee> emp;
     .....
  //Getters And Setters
 }
```

**AbstractDao.java**

```
public abstract class AbstractDao<PK extends Serializable, T> {
private final Class<T> persistentClass;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public AbstractDao(){
this.persistentClass =(Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) 
this.getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[1];
}

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

protected Session getSession(){
  return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
 }

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public T getByKey(PK key) {
 return (T) getSession().get(persistentClass, key);
}

public void persist(T entity) {
 getSession().persist(entity);
}

public void update(T entity) {
 getSession().update(entity);
}

public void delete(T entity) {
 getSession().delete(entity);
}

protected Criteria createEntityCriteria(){
 return getSession().createCriteria(persistentClass);
}
}
```

**BloodGroupDaoImpl.java**

```
@Repository("bloodDao")
public class BloodDaoImpl extends AbstractDao<Integer, BloodGroup> 
 implements BloodDao {

 static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserDaoImpl.class);

  public void save(BloodGroup bloodgroup) {
    persist(bloodgroup);
     }

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<BloodGroup> listBloodGroup() {
 Criteria criteria = createEntityCriteria();
 return (List<BloodGroup>) criteria.list();
 }
 }
```

**SectionDaoImpl.java**

```
@Repository("sectionDao")
public class SectionDaoImpl extends AbstractDao<Integer,Section>implements 
 SectionDao{

@Override
public void save(Section section) {
  persist(section);
 }

@Override
public List<Section> allSection() {
  Criteria criteria = createEntityCriteria();
  return (List<Section>) criteria.list();
 }
 }
```

**EmployeesDaoImpl.java**

```
@Repository("employeeDao")
public class EmployeeDaoImpl extends AbstractDao<Integer,Employee> 
implements EmployeeDao{

@Override
public void save(Employee employee) {
  persist(employee);
 }
@Override
public List<Employee> allEmployee() {
  Criteria criteria = createEntityCriteria();
  return (List<Employee>) criteria.list(); 
/*This shows list of employee 
table with foreign key. **I want to show list of employee with correspondent 
value of **BloobGroup** and **Section**.*/
 }
}
```

**BloodGroupServiceImpl.java**

```
@Service("bloodGroupService")
@Transactional
public class bloodGroupServiceImpl implements bloodGroupService {

@Autowired
private BloodDao dao;
@Override
public void saveBloodGroup(BloodGroup bloodgroup) {
  dao.save(bloodgroup);
}

public List<BloodGroup> allBloodGroup() {
 return dao.listBloodGroup();
}
```

**SectionServiceImpl.java**

```
@Service("sectionService")
@Transactional
public class sectionServiceImpl implements sectionService{

@Autowired
private SectionDao dao;

@Override
public void save(Section section) {
 dao.save(section);
}

@Override
public List<Section> allSection() {
  return dao.allSection();
}
```

**EmployeeServiceImpl.java**

```
@Service("EmployeeService")
@Transactional
public class employeeServiceImpl implements employeeService{

@Autowired
private EmployeeDao dao;

@Autowired
private BloodDao bloodDao;

@Autowired
private SectionDao sectionDao;

@Override
public List<Employee> allEmployee() {
  return dao.allEmployee();
}

@Override
public void save(Employee employee, int bloodgroup,int section) {
    employee.setBloodgroup(bloodDao.findById(bloodgroup));
    employee.setSection(sectionDao.findById(section));
    dao.save(employee);
 }
}
```

**AppController.java**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class AppController {

@Autowired
employeeService wService;

@RequestMapping(value = { "/employee-list" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String listWaheeb(ModelMap model) {
    model.addAttribute("loggedinuser", getPrincipal());
    List<Employee> emp = wService.allEmployee();
    model.addAttribute("empList", emp);
    return "allEmployee";
   }
}
```

**allEmployee.jsp**

```
<div class="content">
<table id="mytable">

 <tbody>
 <c:forEach items="${empList}" var="eList">
  <tr>
  <td>${eList.wid}</td>
  <td>${eList.wname}</td>
    <!-- for BloodGroup and Section fields-->
  </tr>
 </c:forEach>
 </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
```

**My Query is**

> Select employee.wname,bloodgroup.blood_name,section.sname
>   from employee,bloodgroup,section
>   where employee.bidd = bloodgroup.bid
>   and   employee.sidd = section.sid
>   and   employee.wname = 'abc';

How can i write this in hibernate criteria to return List

Comment: Show your repository and what you have tried

Comment: @Hitham S. AlQadheeb : Please check my code again and Help me

Comment: In EmployeeDao add a method to get employee by name.  Then, just add fetch=FetchType.LAZY to section and bloodgroup in Employee